# Xamarin.forms compilation error in Visual studio 2015

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I have been create Xamarin.forms(portable) Hello world project in Visual Studio 2015, but when I try to build, I get the following errors:

error 1 :

> The Bonjour backend failed to initialize, automatic Mac build server discovery will not be available

error 2:

> No resource identifier found for attribute ‘touchscreenBlocksFocus’ in package ‘android

Note : I don't add Mac Agent and my OS is Windows 8 and I can't upgrade to Windows 8.1 or 10. Windows phone Emulator require at least Windows 8.1 .

Comment: Have you installed the latest Android SDK with regards to your Android issue?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following method?

> Just go to My Computer or My PC, right-click and select "Manage" or
>   just search for 'Services' then go to 'Services and Applications' then
>   'Services'. Look for 'Bonjour Services' and click on it. Now go to
>   'General' tab and look for Startup type. Change it from Disabled to
>   Automatic. Click 'Apply' then on 'Service Status' click 'Start' then
>   OK.

[Source](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=12119#c7)

Comment: I change Startup type from Automatic to Disabled, And now project build successfully.

Comment: I have the same problem, and I am unable to find the `Bonjour Services` how can I install it?

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure 'Bonjour Services' are running.

Clean and Rebuild the project has fixed my issue.